# Identifying dependency and composition between entities

Tags: uml, class-diagram, erd

I am new to learning UML andI have an ERD diagram to be converted to a class diagram as an exercise.
Two entities in it are **InvoiceItem** and **InventoryItem**.
InvoiceItem has attributes quantity added while attributes of InventoryItem are itemNo,ItemDescription,QuantityInStock.

When I am converting to class diagram is their a **dependency** between these two entities.In the ERD the two entities are linked as [image]

What is denoted by the circle near the entity InvoiceItem?

Also InvoiceItem is linked  with another entity **Invoice** which has the attributes InvoiceNo,InvoiceDate,isPaid.
Can I consider the relationship between Invoice and InvoiceItem  as a **composition**.  Because invoice is composed of invoiceItems and if invoice is deleted InvoiceItems too gets deleted.

Answer (score 1):

The circle in ERD denotes the lower multiplicity bound of 0 (see diagram bellow). This tells that not each InventoryItem has an InvoiceItem.

Yes, the relationship between Invoice and InvoiceItem is composition for the reason you stated. This is a clear, perfect example of a composition.

And the target diagram:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Shouldn't the relationship between InvoiceItem and InventoryItem be a **dependency** shown by - - - - - - - ->

Comment: Dependency is generic relationship and therefore can be also used. However, association gives more information, adds semantic meaning, through multiplicities, containment, role names, etc. With pure dependency you cannot tell that an InventoryItem can have several InvoiceItems for example, you can only indicate they they are somehow dependent.